# Pegar DIV através de um custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tenho várias `DIVs` como a do código abaixo.

```js
  <div class="col-md-10" ordained-field="0"></div>
```

Como eu faço para pegar todas pelo attributo que eu criei `ordained-field`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só precisei definir o tipo de elemento eu quero trazer e a minha custom attribute entre colchetes:

```js
console.log($('div[ordained-field]'))
```

Encontrei também uma busca através de um custom attribute com valores:

```js
$('div[ordained-field="1"]')
```

Comment: apenas troque "ordained-field" para "data-ordained-field" para ser uma propriedade valida no html.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp